# ¿como puedo hacer un actualizar en un formulario con ajax en laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esta pequeña tabla en la columna de opciones el el segundo boton que es el de editar, me gustaria que al darle click me abriera un modal como el que muestro a continuacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que me cargara los datos y que pueda cambiar los valores que yo quiera de acuerdo a la fila que seleccione y que al darle guardar me actualize los datos.

De acuerdo a mis investigaciones, tengo una idea de como hacerlo pero no se como llevarlo a codigo, por decir en el boton de la columna opciones tebgo que hacer una funcion onclick donde me traiga los datos al modal, posteriormente con ajax que me actualize mi tabla a la hora de dar clic en Guardar.
no se por donde empezar me podrian ayudar hacer esta funcion.

Este es mi **JS:**

```
$("#myModal1").on("click", ".modalForm", function(){
    var parametros= {
        "nombre" : $("input#txt_nombre").val(),
        "inicio" : $("input#txt_inicio").val(),
 "final" : $("input#txt_final").val(),
        "ejecuta" : $("input#txt_ejecuta").val(),
 "persona" : $("input#txt_persoma").val(),
        "observaciones" : $("input#txt_observaciones").val()
    };
```

Aqui esta mi **tabla**:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
            <th width="25%">Tipo de medida</th>
            <th>Fecha inicio</th>
            <th>Fecha final</th>
            <th>Ejecuta</th>
            <th>Persona</th>
            <th>Observaciones</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>                             
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if(count($TablaProvidencia)==0)
            <tr><td colspan="7" class="text-center">Sin registros</td></tr>
        @else
            @foreach($TablaProvidencia as $provide)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $provide->providencia}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $provide->fechainicio }}</td>  
                    <td>{{ $provide->fechafin }}</td>  
                    <td>{{ $provide->ejecutor }}</td>  
                    <td>{{ $provide->persona }}</td>  
                    <td>{{ $provide->observacion }}</td>  
                    <td>
                            <a href="{{ url('agregar-medidas/'.$provide->id.'/eliminar')}}" type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Eliminar Registro" class="btn btn-success btn-simple btn-xs">
                            <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-simple btn-xs" value={{$provide->id}} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>

                    </td>                           
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y aqui esta mi **modal:**

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content"> 
            <!--Cabecera del modal-->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Actualizar</h4>
            </div> 

              <!-- FORMULARIO -->
              <form action="#" class="modalForm">

                <!--Contenido del modal-->
                <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xm-6">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tipo_medida" name="tipo_medida" placeholder="Tipo de medida" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xm-6">
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" id="fecha_inicio" name="fecha_inicio" placeholder="Fecha Inicio">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fecha_final" name="fecha_final" placeholder="Fecha Final" >
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xm-6">
                        <input class="form-control " type="text" id="ejecuta" name="ejecuta" placeholder="Ejecuta">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xm-6">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="persona" name="Persona" placeholder="Persona" >
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xm-6">
                            <input class="form-control " type="text" id="observaciones" name="observaciones" placeholder="Observaciones">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                </div> 
                <!--Final del modal-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" id="guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Guardar</button>
                </div>

             </form>
             <!-- FORMULARIO - END -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: te hace falta mostrar tu codigo javascript

Comment: ok, muchas gracias ya lo mostre, ayudame porvaor